# Capturing the values of jquery slider

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created jquery slider which works fine. I have divided slider into three category.

```
    var setRatingValue = function() {
        // Set text
        var ratingValue = $("#rating-slider").slider("value");
        $("#rating-value").text('yellow');
        // Change the background colour of the slider
        //var hsl = "hsl("+ratingValue+", "+50+"%, "+50+"%)";
var color = '';
if(ratingValue > 0 & ratingValue <= 30)
    color = 'red';

else if(ratingValue > 30 & ratingValue <= 70)
    color = 'blue';

else if(ratingValue > 70 & ratingValue < 100)
    color = 'green';

        $(".ui-slider-range").css("background", color);
        // Set text colour
        $("#rating-value").css("color", color);
    };
```

Slider looks like this : http://jsfiddle.net/BxY99/2/ Which is not same which I have used.

It take continous values of slider.

I want to alert the value of slider **Only if it's value change from one of these cateogry (0 to 30, 31 to 70, 71 to 100).**

Currently what happens it alerts each value when slider is moved.

Any help is appreciable

Comment: For which browser, you are facing the issue

Comment: Can you show us a fiddle with the slider you actually used?

Comment: First off, you've got some syntax errors.  `&` is a bit-wise operator in JavaScript. You want the `&&` boolean operator (which means both terms must evaluate to true).

Comment: @JordyvanKuijk: I tried but my fiddle does not work

Comment: Did you check my fiddle: __http://jsfiddle.net/gs27C/1/__ - was that the behaviour you wanted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the slide event or the change event that the [**API**](http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#event-slide) has,

Those events pass as function parameters the `event` and a `ui` object where you can retrieve the value by `ui.value`,

Then you can use:

```
$(".slider").slider({
    value: 50,
    slide: function (event, ui) {
        myFunction(event, ui);
    }
});
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gs27C/1/)